# Chaining timeouts results in last timeout rejected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, bluebird

I'm currently trying to chain some promises with timeouts and no matter which timeout is reached it's always reporting the last one. I tried it with bluebird and Q with the same result, so I think I have a general problem.

The code basically looks like this:

```js
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.delay(2000)
  .then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(2000);
  })
  .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 1')
  .then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(500);
  })
  .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 2')
  .then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(500);
  })
  .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 3');
```

I'm getting "Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: Timeout 3". What I want is getting the Timeout 1. I tried catching after each timeout, but I'm getting the same.

Is there any way to get it working without splitting it up completly?

Comment: When you have multiple timeouts for the same period of time there is no guarantee on the order they'll run as far as I know.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum In fact even if they don't have same period of time there is no guarantee at all. So using timers in this way doesn't work at all :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have 3 timeouts that all require that everything (your whole chain) finishes within 1s.
I've got the feeling that you actually want to make 3 timeouts for each of the successive tasks:

```
Promise.delay(2000)
.then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(2000)
    .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 1');
})
.then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(500)
    .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 2');
})
.then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(500)
    .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 3');
});
```

This will be rejected after 3s with the Timeout 1.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do. I tried it similar yesterday, but it seemed to be mixed up. Now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bluebird makes no guarantees on the execution order of timers. So if you set three timeouts set to the same time span we don't enforce which one gets executed. As you can see if you run this code in the browser `"Timeout 1"` will log and not timeout 3:

```js
var p = Promise.delay(2000)
  .then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(2000);
  })
  .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 1')
  .then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(500);
  })
  .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 2')
  .then(function() {
    return Promise.delay(500);
  })
  .timeout(1000, 'Timeout 3');

p.reflect().then(function(res){
  document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res.reason().message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/2.9.6/bluebird.js"></script>
```

Technically bluebird is keeping its contract. After the specified amount of time assuming no abnoramalities if the promise is not already resolved it is rejected. This is true regardless of which timer fires here.
This is just ordering of timers - you should instead give them different timeout values.

Of course if you add a `.catch(function(){})` after the first timeout (preferably a typed one and not just a general one)  after the first `.timeout` you will get a different result.

Answer (score 0):

`delay` and `timeout` use the `setTimeout` function of the environment which in node.js gives absolutely no guarantee in what order timers will run. You basically need to assume that a `setTimeout(..., 10)` might run after `setTimeout(..., 10000)` so making your code rely on earlier timer to run after later timer is broken.

Comment: Actually - in the browser it's specified, quoting the relevant part of the timers spec: `Wait until any invocations of this algorithm started before this one whose timeout is equal to or less than this one's have completed.` - it's node that makes no guarantees: `Node.js makes no guarantees about the exact timing of when the callback will fire, nor of the ordering things will fire in.`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that explains why I always get Timeout 1 in the browser... but the op is using node.js indeed